# Can array contain text as a name of something and in same way number as a value?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm creating app that shows you name of google search and you press higher or lower button to answer it. But right now i don't know exactly how to do it so i came to idea to make array and put a name as a question and number of searches as a number or value. I did search on google but nothing shows me the right method to do this. If it's not possible can you explain what is better way to make this possible.

Comment: Perhaps use a TreeMap?

Comment: I will try that to thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Map<String, Integer>` where the key is a question and the value is number of searches.
[Map reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_map_interface.htm)

Another option is to use 2 lists with synced indexes, one `List` will hold the questions and the second list for number of searches.

Comment: Note that Map is an Interface. You need a class that implements Map.

Comment: Thanks for your point, didn't want to choose the implementation for him

Answer (score -1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but what you are asking is how to have an array of both a string and number?
If I am correct in understanding what you are wanting to do, you can't do this with just one array (See ronginats' answer for a solution which is close to this). I would make two parallel arrays, one which stores the google search and the other storing the number, but both values share an index. So you could do something like the following:

```
String[] searchItems = {"What is stack overflow?", "bing.com", "Does youtube own google?"}; //All of the searches
long[] timesSearched = {5000, 10, 250}; //Times each have been searched

system.out.println(searchItems[0] + " has been searched " + timesSearched[0] + " times.");
```

Comment: Using parallel arrays is usually a sign of poor design. Use a TreeMap instead.